# What does it mean by a "pointer points to another memory location"?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I know that a pointer variable stores the memory address of another variable. But what does it mean by *"Pointer points to another memory location"?* What does it mean by *"pointer points to..."*?

Comment: t means that the pointer points to "the memory address of another variable", i.e. the value of the pointer variable is "the memory address of another variable."

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie Thanks!

Comment: "Pointer `p` points to variable `x`" is just another way of saying "The value of variable `p`  is the memory address of variable `x`." At least in the most straightforward implementations.

Comment: @NSR It is a test on an interview. A candidate gave a wrong answer that the pointer points to the left and he was told that the pointer points to another memory location: it points to the right.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally, a [variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(computer_science)) is an association between a name and a location in memory. It can be more complicated than that in other languages, and other information is usually associated with the variable (e.g. a type), but this is not relevant here.

A pointer variable is a variable (a name that references some area of memory), but what's in that area of memory? What's the [pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) itself? Well, it's a memory address, a way of referencing another memory location. Rather than saying "the pointer *has for value* this other memory location", we say the pointer *references* or *points to* this other memory location.

We might have a name for that other memory location. That would make it a variable. As such, we also say the pointer *references* or *points to* this other variable.

In the following, we have a pointer `p` that points to variable `i`:

```c
int i = 1000;
int *p = &i;
```

We might have this memory:

```
p at addr 0x1122       |      ⋮       |
i at addr 0x3344       +--------------+
                       |       0x3344 | 0x1122
                       +--------------+
                       |      ⋮       |
                       +--------------+
                       |         1000 | 0x3344
                       +--------------+
                       |      ⋮       |
```

---

So what's the difference between the following two statements:

```c
int *q = p;
int j = *p;
```

In the first, we are copying the pointer itself, the memory address.

In the second, we are indirectly accessing `i`. We are telling C to *dereference* the pointer, which means to access that to which the pointer points. This is `i`.

We might have this memory:

```
p at addr 0x1122       |      ⋮       |
i at addr 0x3344       +--------------+
q at addr 0x5566       |       0x3344 | 0x1122
j at addr 0x7788       +--------------+
                       |      ⋮       |
                       +--------------+
                       |         1000 | 0x3344
                       +--------------+
                       |      ⋮       |
                       +--------------+
                       |       0x3344 | 0x5566
                       +--------------+
                       |      ⋮       |
                       +--------------+
                       |         1000 | 0x7788
                       +--------------+
                       |      ⋮       |
```

What happens to the others if you change one of `*p`, `*q`, `i` and `j`? I'll let you hypothesize and experiment :)

Comment: I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It points to another memory location exactly the same way a postal address on the postcard you recently received points to your home. A pointer contains the address of a memory location. A postal address contains the address of a physical location - be it a building, an apartment, a post office box... "Points to" thus means "refers to a location of". That's true of both pointers and postal addresses.

It's not true that a pointer must point to **another** memory location. It's true that the vast majority of pointers in use in real-world software indeed point somewhere else. That is `99.9...%` of pointers in existence in the world at any given time, with an additional 15 nines after the decimal point. At the very, very least.

But a pointer can surely point to itself, too. Sometimes it's handy if all you want is to stick a pointer somewhere, and learn where this "somewhere" is. For example, in most C and C++ implementations, the following short program will print the stack address where the pointer variable resided at runtime (yes, the implementations don't have to store that variable on the stack, but in most real-world cases it will be a stack address indeed):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  void *pointer = &pointer;
  printf("The variable \"%s\" is stored on stack at address %p\n", "pointer", &pointer);
}
```

For example, I got the following output:

```
The variable "pointer" is stored on stack at address 0x7fff2350e9f8
```

A pointer may also point to **no** memory location. A null pointer would be an example of that:

```
// Conformant C and C++
int *nullPointer1 = NULL; // Idiomatic C
int *nullPointer2 = 0;
// Conformant C++
int *nullPointer3 = nullptr; // Idiomatic C++
int *nullPointer4 = {}; // Idiomatic C++
std::unique_ptr<int> nullPointer5; // This is really C++ - raw pointers should be used only when truly needed, in library code etc.
```

Such pointers are OK, but the only valid use for them is to check that they are indeed null. They cannot be dereferenced - I mean, yes, you can dereference them, but it's undefined behavior, and modern compilers treat undefined behavior in your code as a license to delete such code. That is, if you dereference a null pointer, and the compiler can prove that it's always the case, the code that does such dereferencing may be removed. Examples (gcc 10.1 x64, `-O3`):

```
int main() {
  int *pointer = 0;
  int b = *pointer;
}

// produces same assembly output as
int main() { return 0; }
```

It gets better. This code:

```
int main() {
   int *pointer = 0;
   *pointer = 5;
}
```

when compiled, the 2nd line is modified as if you wrote `*pointer = 0`, and right after the assignment follows the `ub2` "instruction" that triggers the undefined instruction exception. In other words: if you ran this in a process where 0-th memory page was mapped in, it'd fail, even though loading `5` at address `0` would be a valid operation! Instead, it'd load `0` at address `0`, and then fail with an exception.